# как удалить сущность в JPA

Tags: jpa, entity

Если я удаляю сущность вот так:

```
public void remove(Case lawsuit) {
    Case c = entityManager.find(Case.class, lawsuit.getId());
    entityManager.remove(c);
}
```

то она не удаляется, а если вот так:

```
public void remove(Case lawsuit) {
    Case c = entityManager.find(Case.class, lawsuit.getId());

    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    entityManager.remove(c);
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

то нормально удаляется. Почему у меня только так получается удалить? Вот сущность сама:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cases")
public class Case {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private String caseNumber;

    private String dataI;

    private String dataII;

    private String dataIII;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "judgeID")
    private Judge judge;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "lawyerID")
    private Lawyer lawyer;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "clientID")
    private Client client;

    @Enumerated(value = EnumType.ORDINAL)
    private CaseStatus statusI;

    @Enumerated(value = EnumType.ORDINAL)
    private CaseStatus statusII;

    @Enumerated(value = EnumType.ORDINAL)
    private CaseStatus statusIII;

    private String document;

    //геттеры, сеттеры
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как влияет remove на сущность в каждом возможном состоянии описывает раздел 3.2.3 спеки [JPA 2.1 spec](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/index.html)

1. Если статус new, операция игнорируется, однако зависимые Entity могут поменять статус на removed, если у них есть аннотации каскадных изменений и они имели статус managed,
2. Если статус managed, то статус меняется на removed и запись объект в базе данных будет удалена при commit'е транзакции (так же произойдут операции remove для всех каскадно зависимых объектов),
3. Если статус removed, то операция игнорируется,
4. Если статус detached, будет выкинут exception сразу или на этапе commit'а транзакции